# Julia doing something strange with assignments

Tags: debugging, julia

I am trying to learn Julia by repeating some of the easy ProjectEuler problems in Julia. Everything has been really smooth so far, up until I encountered this frustrating problem. I spent some time debugging my code, and here's what I found:
(Hopefully I'm not missing something really stupid here)

```
function is_abundant(n::Int)                        #just a function
    return prod(map(x->int((x[1]^(x[2]+1)-1)/(x[1]-1)),factor(n))) > 2 * n
end

abundants=[12]     #there should be a better way to initialize an Array
for i=13:28120
    if is_abundant(i)
        push!(abundants,i)
    end
end

le=abundants;      #The following lines are the problems
ri=abundants;
d=length(abundants)
println(d)
pop!(le)
shift!(ri)
println(le==ri, " ", endof(ri), " ", endof(abundants))
```

The output I get is:

`6964
true 6962 6962`

which means that Julia has changed all three sets of `le` , `ri` and `abundants` with each of `pop!` and `shift!` commands. I was able to work around this bug/problem by using a dumb extra identity mapping:

```
le=map(x->x,abundants)
ri=map(x->x,abundants)
```

Now the output would change to what I initially expected:

`6964
false 6963 6964`

My question is, if this is not a bug, why is Julia keeping an equivalence relation between `le` , `ri` and `abundants` sets in the first place? Also, can anyone reproduce this behaviour? I am using  Julia "Version 0.3.0-rc3+14 (2014-08-13 16:01 UTC)" on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: There is only ever one array, you're just making many references to it. Related: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#i-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function-modified-it-inside-that-function-but-on-the-outside-the-variable-x-is-still-unchanged-why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`le` and `ri` both point to the same list that `abundants` points to, so this is expected behavior - they are all operating on the same memory. [This part of the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/faq/#i-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function-modified-it-inside-that-function-but-on-the-outside-the-variable-x-is-still-unchanged-why) might help you understand. Or possibly the [MATLAB differences](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/noteworthy-differences/#noteworthy-differences-from-matlab) section, as it is different in MATLAB (but most other languages are like Julia).

For

```
abundants=[12] #there should be a better way to initialize an Array
```

how about

```
abundants = {}  # Vector of anything
```

or

```
abundants = Int[]  # Vector of ints
```

and instead of your `map(x->x,...)`, you can just use `copy`.